# scroll down and click on the element is not working

Tags: selenium-webdriver, appium-android

providing this to scroll , then click on the element which text value i am declared in description

AndroidElement  quot=(AndroidElement)driver.findElementById("com.mrk.compaq.application:id/divider21");

```
    MobileElement list = (MobileElement) driver.findElement(
            MobileBy.AndroidUIAutomator(
                    "new UiScrollable(new UiSelector()).scrollIntoView("
                            +"new UiSelector().description(\"*Enter UTR No.*\"));"));
    System.out.println(list.getLocation());
    //list.click();
```

but the result is its scrolling up and down but  not able to click on the element .

Answer (score 0):

Your click line is commented out.
Uncomment it:    `//list.click();` ->    `list.click();`

Comment: i know , anything extra you can tell .